# using aleph to connect using digest authentication

Tags: clojure, aleph

I would like to use the aleph library but cant find a way to authenticate using "digest authentication". I have solved this with `clj-http.client` but I really would like to use aleph because of the web socket possibilities.

This is the code I use with `clj-http.client`:

```clj
(client/post 
    url 
    {:as :stream
     :digest-auth [usr pass]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Aleph does not support digest auth. clj-http is able to support it by leveraging Apache HttpComponents' implementation, but there is no support available in Aleph's backing library Netty.